# Angular 2 CRUD Components

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, components

I'm getting started with Angular 2 with TypeScript and I'm trying to find the best way of organizing my application.

Imagine that I want to CRUD a product. Since I want each CRUD operation to have different views should I create a component for each operation? For example: createProduct.component; editProduct.component; getProduct.component; etc.; that all reuse the product class and the product.service in order to make http requests to the server?

I think this makes sense, but I'm not sure there's a better way to do it and since Angular 2 is fairly new, I'm having trouble finding proper documentation for this problem. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a `/+product` folder
- Add all product components (edit/view/create), also include the test(product.spec.ts) files
- Create a `/services` folder, add the `product.service`

Comment: So I should have a different component for every CRUD operation. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, because the `edit` and create view is usually more complex, with validation controls/messages

Comment: So if I have a lot of CRUD in my application, my main component will have a lot of includes, right?

Comment: Not at all. What do you mean by includes?

Comment: Won't I have the need to have an include for each component I have? If I have one for each CRUD operation and have many CRUD, I reckon that's going to be a lot of includes.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the official **Style Guide** here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html

Comment: I don't think it has style guides for what I'm asking, but I'll still take a look :) Thanks!